# Listing the parameters of Get-Eventlog cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I need to use the Get-Eventlog cmdlet to display just the log name and the retention period.  I've used Get-Eventlog -list | format-table log, retain
but it only displays the log and the "retain" column is empty.  What is the parameter for the retention period so the numbers will display along with the log name?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The objects returned by `Get-EventLog` have no such property as `Retain`. However, they *do* have a property named `MinimumRetentionDays`. Maybe that's what you're after. Just do a `Get-EventLog -List | Select *` to see what all properties are available, so that you can avoid trying to select properties that don't exist.

`Get-EventLog -List | Select Log, MinimumRetentionDays`

Comment: Fantastic!  Yes I believe that is what I am looking for.  I am VERY new to PowerShell and having one heck of a time in getting myself to learn it.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: @SteveB My pleasure. Feel free to upvote and accept. :)

Answer (score 1):

The get-member cmdlet will give you the properties and methods from an object.  In this case `get-eventlog -list | get-member` will list the system.diagnostics.eventlog members.